# Datos en sql tipo DATE me los trae en otro formato. C#

Tags: c#

como andan? Tengo una duda y es la siguiente:

Cuando hago un **insert** en una tabla donde tiene un atributo de tipo **DATE** lo paso con el siguiente formato: AAAA-MM-DD

El problema es que, cuando los traigo a mi programa de C#, me los trae de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para ir descartando problemas, en la base de datos, los almacena de la forma en que hago el **insert**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer, para que este dato "**fecha**"de la forma correcta. Ya que yo los almaceno correctamente.

Acá el **Select**:

```
select id as 'ID', fecha as 'Fecha', razonSocial as 'Proveedor', total as 'Total' from compra inner join proveedor on compra.id_proveedor = proveedor.idProveedor
```

Comment: ¿En qué formato quieres la fecha?

Comment: @JosueArriola en el que hago el INSERT, que es el AAAA-MM-DD

Comment: Puedes intentar con `string nfecha = fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");` en `C#` donde `fecha` es la que extraes de la DB y `nfecha` es el que mostrarás, intenta así y si no te funciona veamos con un `convert` en el query . Saludos.

Comment: no, no se puede. En el query como podria ser?

Comment: Creo que para facilitar todo debes colocar tu código para ver exactamente por que no funciona. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor incluye el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede hacerlo desde el script en sql ó convirtiendolo como cadena con el formato dado desde el codigo.

Ejemplo en sql server:

```
select id as 'ID', FORMAT(fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as 'Fecha', razonSocial as 'Proveedor', total as 'Total' from compra inner join proveedor on compra.id_proveedor = proveedor.idProveedor
```

en codigo c#

```
DateTime dateTime=DateTime.Now;//es como ejemplo, solo sustituyelo por el de tu modelo
string strfecha = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

La cadena que recibes de la base de datos, debes transformarla a tipo DateTime para poder manipular el formato de la fecha usando: fecha.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")